# Show that every finite integral domain is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that every finite integral domain is a field.

I have shown that every nonzero element in a finite ring with an identity is either a zero divisor or a unit.

Comment: Well, you have asked it at least... Now, what do you want to do? What is the definition of a integral domain you want to use, which definition of a field comes to mind?

Oh, and btw, partially dublicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266874/proving-that-elements-in-a-finite-ring-are-zero-divisors-or-units-and-deducing-t

Comment: An integral domain has no zero divisors.

Comment: I was going to use the definition that a ring is a field if it is a commutative division ring.  I will need to show commutativity.  I will also need to show that for every nonzero a in R there is a $a^{-1}$ such that $a * a^{-1} = a^{-1} * a = 1$.  This confuses me because I just showed that every element should be a zero divisor or a unit, but now I want there to be an $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x\in R^*$. For any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ $x^k\neq0$, because $R$ is integral domain. But $|R|=n$, $|R^*|=n-1$, so $|\{x^1,..,x^n\}|<n$. There exists $a,b\in \{1,,n\},\ a<b$ such that $x^a=x^b$, thus $x^{b-a}=1$ and $x$ is invertible because $ x^{-1}=x^{b-a-1}$. If every nonzero element is invertible, then $R$ is a field.

Comment: what does R* mean?

Comment: $R^*=R-\{0\}$. Usual definition of integral domain assume, that $R$ is nonzero, thus $R^*$ is nonempty.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was really helpful for understanding it!